# How to identify if a latitude/longitude is within a building r not?

Tags: python, geolocation, geopandas

I have a set of latitude and longitude points and I would like find if the coordinate exists within a building or not (whether it is indoor point or not). Points could be anywhere within US. I would like to find the Shape File that could help me solve this problem.

I tried downloading shape-files from **www.census.gov/** but it does not have any documentation on the granularity of shape-files it does contain. So I am not able to correctly pinpoint on the right set of shape-files I can use

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import shape
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import pandas as pd

p1 = Point(32.999231, -96.773696)

data3 = gpd.read_file(fp)

data3['geometry'].intersects(p1)
data3['geometry'].contains(p1)
```

Final output is Indoor/Outdoor. Need some info on the shape files I can use for this kind of problem.

Comment: I would say that the best shot in terms of building footprint data is this dataset from Microsoft https://github.com/Microsoft/USBuildingFootprints

Comment: Is there a way that I can put www.census.gov shapefiles to some use